# How to use foreign key of sqlite to link three table 1->2->3 different column

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I am having three table i want to link all three table together.
for example :
table1 : create table master (sr_no int,int,name text);

table2 : create table child1 (sr_no int,emplno int,last_name text,foreign key(sr_no) refernces master(sr_no) on delete cascade on update cascade);

table3 : create table child2 (Em int,phone text,foreign key(Em) refernces child1(emplno) on delete cascade on update cascade);

But when inserting data into table3 its show ===> Error: foreign key mismatch

please tell me whts problem 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes

Foreign key DML errors are may be reported if:

- The parent table does not exist, or
- The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint do not exist, or
- **The parent key columns named in the foreign key constraint are not the primary key of the parent table and are not subject to a unique constraint using collating sequence specified in the CREATE TABLE**, or
- The child table references the primary key of the parent without specifying the primary key columns and the number of primary key columns in the parent do not match the number of child key columns.

Is emplno the primary key in child2?

Comment: oh srry its a employ no is primary key But Its not a problem at all, .... thank you

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> the parent key columns must be collectively subject to a UNIQUE constraint or have a UNIQUE index

Add a UNIQUE constraint to `child1`'S `emplno` field, or create a separate index on it.